# Determine all values of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ for which $n +1|n^3 + 3n^2 + n + 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've got to reduce it to this

$n+1|n^3+3n^2+n+2$

$n+1|n^3+3n^2+1$

$n+1|2n^2+1$

$n+1|2n^2+2n-2n+1$

$n+1|2n(n+1)-2n+1$

$n+1|-2n+3-2$

$n+1|-2(n+1)+3$

$n+1|3$

All this using propertie $c|a \land c|b \implies c|a \pm b$, however, I don't know how to find the $n$ integers solutions.

Comment: $\dfrac{n^3+3n^2+n+2}{n+1}=n^2+2n-1+\dfrac{3}{n+1}$ so $n+1$ should be equal to  $\pm3$ and $\pm1$and the solutions are $\pm2,\space -4$ and $0$.

Comment: To solve $\,n+1\mid 3\,$ simply list all divisors $d$ of $3$ then equate them to $n+1,\,$ i.e. $\,n+1 = d\iff n  = d-1,\,$ i.e. subtracting $1$ from all divisors of $d$ yields all solutions $\,n.\ \ $